# Listing pods from inside a pod Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm new to kubernetes. I'm trying to list all the pods in a namespace from inside a pod/container via the javascript client.

```
import k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.Core_v1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('development')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The response error when I look at my pod logs:

```
{ kind: 'Status',
 apiVersion: 'v1',
 metadata: {},
 status: 'Failure',
 message:
  'pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "development"',
 reason: 'Forbidden',
 details: { kind: 'pods' },
 code: 403 } }
```

I believe I need to create a new User or add some permissions to a Role but I'm not sure where and how. Thanks

Comment: You could try applying the role and rolebinding from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813698/access-kubernetes-api-without-kubectl

Comment: It worked :) . You might want to put it in the answer if you want me to mark it solved.

Comment: great, have posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @[Robert Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2779488/robert-panzer) suggested in [Access Kubernetes API without kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813698/access-kubernetes-api-without-kubectl), you can create a role and a rolebinding to enable listing of pods with:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error:

```
'pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "development"',
```

the default service account token is stored in the pod at the location:

```
root@nginx-64f497f8fd-jtvgf:/# ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ 
ca.crt  namespace  token
```

but the default service account dont have access to the cluster resources like the one you are trying to do, so you need to either create a new service account , role , and role binding , and then start the pod with that service account , or bind the default service account to a role with required permissions.

Kuberentes RBAC [details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

[Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)